# How to read office 365 users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jsom, sharepoint-addin

Currently, i am reading user information from user profile in my SharePoint online environment. But i unable to read some information[address, State, zip etc] of user, because office 365 AD sync only list of attributes with SharePoint online user profile  check list [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147510.aspx).

How can i get address,State, and Zip information of user in SharePoint Online using JSOM?.

is there any way to customize my setting to profile sync, so i can enable these attributes to sync in SharePoint online?

or I can read user information from Office 365 AD[Azure AD], is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As you very well noticed unless attributes are specifically synchronized you won't get more data. Currently these attributes are supported by the AD-Sync http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19901.dirsync-list-of-attributes-that-are-synced-by-the-azure-active-directory-sync-tool.aspx

Obviously this would require updating the synchronization connection and only than check User Profile properties for the mapping. At which moment, assuming successful mapping you could envision JSOM to get data. Examples everywhere, e.g. http://www.vrdmn.com/2015/01/set-user-profile-properties-using-jsom.html

Comment: Thanks for quick response, **Marius**. As i understood i try to create custom user profile property to map with required AAD attibutes, unfortunately i **unable to add mapping**. Then i found that's a **limitation in user profile of SharePoint Online**. Please check here[link](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/228383).   Please let me know if i understood wrongly.